# Combining two tables (Join) In data studio

Tags: join, looker-studio

I'm attempting to join two tables in Data Studio. My data sources are Google Ads and Microsoft ads. I'd like to end up with a table that looks like the following [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl41i.png):

| Campaign | Clicks |
| --- | --- |
| Campaign 1 | 500 |
| Campaign 2 | 700 |

The clicks from each table is added together to give a total.

When I attempt to join both tables, I get a result that looks like this ([full example here](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/9dc7051d-4188-46f7-b998-6d7a30860c0b)):

| Campaign | Clicks (Table 1) | Clicks (Table 2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Campaign 1 | 100 | 400 |
| Campaign 2 | 200 | 500 |

The data appears to be joined by 'campaign' but the 'clicks' are not being consolidated into one column, instead the clicks data from both tables are separate.

I've already attempted to solve this issue by:

- Creating calculated fields in the newly blended data (Clicks Table 1+ Clicks Table 2) but this yields strange results when trying to aggregate other metrics.
- Join using 'Clicks', however, this doesn't work as the number of clicks for each campaign is always likely to be different for each data source.
- Change the [join type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiogH.png) from 'Left outer' to right outer, inner, full outer and cross but none of these appear to work either.
- Grouping campaigns by a 'Campaign Group' calculated field using a CASE statement but this doesn't appear to work either- this generally results in only one set of data to show at a time (possibly whichever loads quickest).

[Here's how my blend is setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8ylV.png). You can attempt to reproduce this issue using [this page](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/9dc7051d-4188-46f7-b998-6d7a30860c0b/page/p_9i7rzby1vc).

What is the best way to join both tables and have the metrics (like clicks) properly aggregated?

Answer (score 0):

The values in the two separate fields, `Clicks (Table 1)` and `Clicks (Table 2)` can be consolidated using the [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685):

```
Clicks (Table 1) + Clicks (Table 2)
```

This will work as long as there are no NULL values in either (or both) tables in the [blend](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420), for any given row of data.

This is because `1 + NULL = NULL` (where `1` is used as an example to represent a number) as NULL is not a numeric literal (it's not a number, thus cannot be calculated)

Since this blend has NULL values, one approach is to use the [`IFNULL`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10521929) function ("*returns a result if the input is null, otherwise, returns the input*") below, which treats NULL values as a numeric literal (in this case, 0), so that the values can be calculated:

```
IFNULL(Clicks (Table 1), 0) + IFNULL(Clicks (Table 2), 0)
```

This will ensure that calculations are changed:

- `1 + NULL = NULL` is replaced by `1 + 0 = 1`
- `NULL + NULL = NULL` is replaced by `0 + 0 = 0`

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/3fe3c305-23bc-4c34-b935-4950cb9ba9d6) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gXSZvB1czq-71h_KkO9g64HLDPdxT6wX_8V9oZkE5SU/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]